# Spring security very simple basic authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I've tried to implement a very simple BASIC authentication with Spring Boot, without the deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/a", "/b", "/c", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {     
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
            .username("user")
            .password("{bcrypt}$2y$10$rUzpfbTx9lcIs6N4Elcg2e2DGM4wMwkx0ixom7qLW5kYnztRgT.a2")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

The ignored endpoints work (with a warning: `You are asking Spring Security to ignore Ant [pattern='/swagger-ui.html']. This is not recommended -- please use permitAll via HttpSecurity#authorizeHttpRequests instead.`). For the other, I get an HTTP 403.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: While accessing other API are you providing credential ?

Comment: If you are doing POST request, it can be the CSRF protection. Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` in your `application.properties` file and see the console output after the request is made.

Comment: @AvijitBarua : yes.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusHertdaCoregio . I've been able to make it work with `return http.csrf().disable().build();` and removing `{bcrypt}` in the password String. Please answer to the question so I can accept it.

Comment: `http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);` was the key change for me to make my integration work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing POST request, it can be the CSRF protection. Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` in your `application.properties` file and see the console output after the request is made to see what is happening.

If it is CSRF protection, I recommend you leave it enabled unless you have a requirement that tells you to disable it. You can have more details about Cross Site Request Forgery [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html).

Also, if you want to use the `{bcrypt}` prefix in your password, use the `PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder`. If you want to use only the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` then you have to remove the `{bcrypt}` prefix